# Dropdown List, when no data in database can't input manually

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHaIR.jpg)I'm creating a program, using the dropdown list.
so here is the form "Pilih Unit Mesin", where the machine unit that has the number "Torsi" in the database automatically will appear numbers in the form of "Torsi"

The problem is how if the machine unit has no numbers in database, i hope in the form "Torsi" can be input manually number

Please help, thank you

```
<label>Pilih Unit Mesin</label>
<select class="form-control" name="id_unit" id="id_unit" required="">

<option value=""><b>nama proyek - unit mesin</b></option>
<?php foreach ($mesin as $key => $value) :?>
    <?php if ($value['status_unit'] === '0'): ?> 
        <option <?php echo $unit_selected == $value['id_unit'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> 
        value="<?php echo $value['id_unit'].'">'.' - '.$value['nama_project'].' - '.$value['unit_mesin'].'</option>'; ?>">
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
</select>
</div>

<label>Torsi</label>
<select class="form-control" name="torsi" id="torsi" required="">

<?php foreach ($poross as $key => $val) :?>
    <?php if ($val['torsi_poros'] != null): ?>
        <option <?php echo $poros_selected == $val['id_unit'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> 
        class="<?php echo $val['id_unit'] ?>" value="<?php echo $val['torsi_poros'] ?>"><?php echo $val['torsi_poros'] ?></option>
        <span class="input-group-addon">Kg.mm</span>

        <?php elseif ($val['torsi_poros'] != ""): ?>
        <option <?php echo $poros_selected == $val['id_unit'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> 
                                 class="form-group input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="torsi" type="text" required="" pattern="^(\+|-)?[0-9].*$">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Kg.mm</span>
        </div>     
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
</select><br>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8j8J.jpg)
**Screenshot 1:**
[image]
**Screenshot 2:**
[image]
**Screenshot 3:**
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8La5v.jpg)

Comment: Like, if there _is_ data, show the select, and if there _isn't_, show an input?

Comment: Yes it's sir @kerbholz, do you know how to make the coding?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine multiple array functions to check whether specific key from multidimensional array is not empty :

```
<label>Torsi</label>
<?php
if (empty(array_filter(array_column($poross, 'torsi_poros')))) {
?>
<input type="number" name="torsi" id="torsi" class="form-control" >
<?php } else { ?>
<select class="form-control" name="torsi" id="torsi" required="">

<?php foreach ($poross as $key => $val) :?>
    <?php if ($val['torsi_poros'] != null): ?>
        <option <?php echo $poros_selected == $val['id_unit'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> 
        class="<?php echo $val['id_unit'] ?>" value="<?php echo $val['torsi_poros'] ?>"><?php echo $val['torsi_poros'] ?></option>
        <span class="input-group-addon">Kg.mm</span>

        <?php elseif ($val['torsi_poros'] != ""): ?>
        <option <?php echo $poros_selected == $val['id_unit'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> 
        class="<?php echo $val['id_unit'] ?>" value="<?php echo $val['torsi_poros'] ?>"><?php echo $val['torsi_poros'] ?></option>
        <span class="input-group-addon">Kg.mm</span>
        </div>     
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
<br>
```

Using `array_column` to return the values from a single column in the array, then `array_filter` to discard empty array.

Comment: thank you for answering my question,
when i write the coding as you created my program is still not running, guess there are errors where?

Comment: the fixed view is like the beginning, can't pop up manual input if the data in the database is empty

Comment: so there are no error? could you do a `var_dump($poross);` before the `if()` statement?